# Passing objects from a json response to html using JS

Tags: javascript, html, json

```
        success:function(result){
          $('#date').html(result.messages[0].date);
          $('#username').html(result.messages[0].username);
          $('#message').html(result.messages[0].message);
    }
```

This way I am only getting object 0 data being shown on my html page. Meanwhile result.messages has already 3 objects (0,1,2) and can have unlimited number of objects. How can I fetch all objects one by one and have its result show in my html page.

result.messages is a Json Response:

```
    {"messages": [{"date": "2023-03-24T16:24:14.585Z", "username": "user_1", "message": "Hello"}, {"date": "2023-03-24T16:39:24.096Z", "username": "user_2", "message": "Hi"}, {"date": "2023-03-25T08:31:41.085Z", "username": "user_1", "message": "How are you?"}]}
```

Comment: How do you want to show all the results? In an unordered list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through any array by using the Array.prototype.forEach() method.

In this case, you'll need to iterate through the `messages` array.

Example:

```js
function display(result) {
  result.messages.forEach((msg) => {
    console.log(msg.date, msg.username, msg.message);
    // here is where you can display the messages on your HTML page
    const newMsg = document.createElement("div");

    newMsg.innerHTML = `${msg.date} - ${msg.username}: ${msg.message}`;

    document.body.appendChild(newMsg);
  });
}

display({
  "messages": [{
    "date": "2023-03-24T16:24:14.585Z",
    "username": "user_1",
    "message": "Hello"
  }, {
    "date": "2023-03-24T16:39:24.096Z",
    "username": "user_2",
    "message": "Hi"
  }, {
    "date": "2023-03-25T08:31:41.085Z",
    "username": "user_1",
    "message": "How are you?"
  }]
})
```

For more information about .forEach(), check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

I hope you found my answer helpful :)

Comment: Yes your answer worked!! Thanks. Now what about the messages loading again? I mean I have this function as setInterval, which is being called once every minute, How can I avoid same messages being shown again in html? and only allow new messages if any to show? Is there something like: ```if ( <div>.innerHTML === `${msg.date} - ${msg.username}: ${msg.message}`) { console.log("Not running") } else { //create a new element etc and pass it to html}```

Comment: @CODComputerAtWar an efficient way would be by giving every message a unique id. While rendering the messages, filter the array so only messages with an id HIGHER than the last one are shown. Say the last message has an id of 3, when a new message comes, only messages with an id HIGHER than 3 are rendered. Hope that helps

Comment: I managed that issue. The messages are loading at the corner of the html page, how can I add them all under one class. I have a class called "box_class". I tried newMsg.class = "box_class" but nothing happened, how can I do that??

Comment: Replace `document.body.appendChild(newMsg);
` with `document.querySelector(".box_class").appendChild(newMsg);`